# Compiler errors (expected ')' before ';' token) and break not within loop

Tags: c, loops, compiler-errors, break

I have been getting the follow errors and I'm not sure what to do. I am not sure if I'm not seeing a typo of if it is just wrong. I found this code on a website and was hoping to implement it in a larger program but I am seriously stuck.

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:10:9: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
test.c:15:4: error: break statement not within loop or switch
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{       
    int n, i, count=0;

    printf ("Enter a positive number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    if (i=2; i<=n/2;i++)
    {
            if(n%i==0)            //line 10
            {
                    count++;
                    break;       //line 15
            }
    return 0;
    }       
    if (count==0 && n!=1)
            printf("%d is a prime number",n);
    else
            printf("%d is not a prime number",n);
    return 0;
                                                          1,1           Top
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (i=2; i<=n/2;i++)
```

needs to be a for loop

```
for (i=2; i<=n/2;i++)
```

The former is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Thank you that got rid of the errors. The problem now is that if I enter a prime number the program does nothing but non prime numbers give the correct result.

Comment: comment out `return 0;` in your for loop